SQLConnection inside thread stuck finalization thread
We have a class that reads the database in parallel to the main thread.
public class CardHandligSpeedometer : IDisposable
{
    private Thread m_Thread;

    public CardHandligSpeedometer()
    {
        createThread();        
    }        

    public void StartThread()
    {
        m_IsStopped = false;

        if (m_Thread == null)
        {
            createThread();
        }

        m_Thread.Start();
    }

    public void StopThread()
    {
        m_IsStopped = true;

        if (m_Thread != null)
        {
            m_Thread.Join(500);

            if (m_Thread != null && m_Thread.IsAlive)
            {
                m_Thread.Abort();
            }

            m_Thread = null;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        StopThread();
    }

    void getHandledCard()
    {
       while (!m_IsStopped)
       {                    
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(LetFlowLib.FactoryData.StrCnt))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetHandledCardCountFor2Hours", connection))
                    {
             //code
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(m_Interval);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // code
            }                
        }            
    }

    private void createThread()
    {
        m_Thread = new Thread(getHandledCard);
        m_Thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
        m_Thread.IsBackground = true;
    }
}

A thread is created and started in the main thread
m_CardHandlingSpeedometer = gcnew ltr_GUI::CardHandligSpeedometer(_CTX.GetAppointID(), 30000);
m_CardHandlingSpeedometer->StartThread();

After reading from the database for the first time and exiting 'using', the finalizing thread is blocked.
If GC::Collect(2); and GC::WaitForPendingFinalizers(); are called in the main thread, the program freezes on the method WaitForPendingFinalizers.
But if change SATA to MTA in the creation method createThread(), then everything works fine.
What is the reason for this?

m_Thread.Abort(); - ok, so anything that contains Thread.Abort can't be quite right (with very few exceptions, of which this is not one). Did some sort of "AI Tool" come up with that?

And why is the second snippet not C#?

Is the 30000 you pass to the CardHandligSpeedometer constructor the sleep interval m_Interval? If yes, it is clear why the thread blocks.

The application is written on the framework 4.0

Whatever the framework, C# has no -> operator. Never had. That looks more like C++.

It's very  old project  using C++/CLI and C#

:D Especially when it comes to threading and GC, that would have been a very important thing to mention in the question ... :)

Just out of curiosity: That doesn't look like something C++ cannot do natively. Why the hassle? (If you happen to know. I am always interested in why decisions were made as they were in cases like this.)

@SullenMan use async/await as you aren't running on .NET Framework 4.0 to begin with. Unless you're targeting Windows XP. No Windows version ever came with 4.0. All supported Windows versions come with a newer one, version which can't be downgraded. All Windows 11 versions come with 4.8.

As for reading the database in parallel (ie using multiple connections), that's most likely increasing contention and blocking instead of improving performance. If you want to do stuff in the background, you already could using delegates and eg BeginInvoke and EndInvoke, even without async/await, ever since .NET Framework 1.0. Create and dispose the connection inside the delegate and you won't have issues with GC. Or use a BackgroundWorker, with the connection created and used inside the DoWork handler

@PanagiotisKanavos I have already tried using Timer and opened SqlConnection inside the Tick event handler - the result is the same

If you used the same buggy code, especially the unnecessary C++ code, you'd get the same bug. If you use System.Threading.Timer the code will run on a background thread so what you really need is to use Control.Invoke or Control.BeginInvoke to update the UI with the results. Tutorials all the way back to 2002 show this.

Before async/await people used BeginXXX commands like SqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader to run code asynchronously and either call a callback method once the command completed, or use EndXXX methods to synchronously wait and get the results. You can also use a BackgroundWorker class/component and call its RunWorkerAsync from any timer to trigger another execution, provided it's not busy.


the program freezes on the method WaitForPendingFinalizers.

Because you have a deadlock: the main threading is waiting on GC, and GC can't start because it's waiting for the other thread, which is stuck waiting on a call which needs to be marshalled back to the main thread, which is waiting on GC.......

But if change SATA to MTA in the creation method createThread(), then everything works fine.

I think you meant STA. Clearly there is a call somewhere (probably the dispose) which needs to be marshalled back (as you have an STA set up already), and declaring thsi thread as MTA is basically saying "I don't care, just execute it on this thread".

This code is just the complete wrong way to go about concurrent and asynchronous database calls.
The use of Thread.Abort is also an extremely bad idea, and doesn't work at all in .NET Core and version 5+.
Instead, use async and await with a CancellationToken
private async Task GetHandledCard(TimeSpan waitTime, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        try
        {
            using SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(LetFlowLib.FactoryData.StrCnt);
            connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
            using SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetHandledCardCountFor2Hours", connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            // use cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync or cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync etc with cancellationToken
            await Task.Delay(waitTime, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //code
        }                
    }
}

And then call it
using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
var task = Task.Run(() => GetHandledCard(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), cts.Token), cts.Token);
// do more stuff
await task;


The application is written on the framework 4.0

And therefore what? The only bit that wouldn't work is await using, everything else is fully supported.

I'm sorry, but I didn't ask for an alternative. I was asking why the code works as described

I am guessing because there is already an STA-Thread in your app: The GUI Thread (aka Event-Dispatch Thread aka Main Thread aka ... )

@SullenMan OK added some explanation. My point stands, this needs to be rewritten.

@Charlieface Heads up: turns out the app is C++/CLI & C#/.Net Framework ... (see comments on question).

@Charlieface, sorry, and where is the marshalling here, nothing is transmitted between the threads? Or is it because of the different languages

Tasks are a different abstraction. They also support async. Which means: "there is no thread" instead of blocking one to perform a "wait".

@Charlieface   Thanks for the answer, but could you explain where marshaling occurs here

I'm not certain, but probably somewhere within SqlClient.
